# Linear Trendline does show up wrong in x,y chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, trendlines

I have a simple set of GPS data for posts of a solar farm and want to add a trendline in a x,y chart to visualize the tolerance to the alignment of said posts. It works with the height of the posts displayed over the northing but for the easting excel just throws the trendline way out, nowhere near the actual points. For other data sets it doesn't even create trendlines besides adding a legend name.
Is it my Excel or am I doing something wrong..

[image: Excel screenshot]

```
Header>> Delimiter() FileFormat(Name    Lon(East)   Lat(North)  Ht(G)
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-1_stk    684256.317  6402786.112 347.762
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-2_stk    684256.311  6402780.788 347.838
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-3_stk    684256.297  6402774.777 347.928
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-4_stk    684256.292  6402768.77  348.035
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-5_stk    684256.296  6402762.292 348.137
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-6_stk    684256.3    6402755.716 348.195
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-7_stk    684256.302  6402748.904 348.342
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-8_stk    684256.295  6402742.416 348.452
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-9_stk    684256.298  6402736.421 348.516
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-10_stk   684256.289  6402730.406 348.623
36-004-INT-R1-P1N-L-S1-11_stk   684256.285  6402725.106 348.698
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-1_stk    684262.611  6402786.126 347.895
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-2_stk    684262.615  6402780.771 347.952
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-3_stk    684262.623  6402774.77  348.05
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-4_stk    684262.619  6402768.811 348.155
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-5_stk    684262.614  6402762.259 348.264
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-6_stk    684262.61   6402755.691 348.384
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-7_stk    684262.611  6402755.103 348.374
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-8_stk    684262.613  6402748.904 348.494
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-9_stk    684262.606  6402742.424 348.606
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-10_stk   684262.617  6402736.387 348.687
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-11_stk   684262.591  6402730.388 348.782
36-004-INT-R2-P1N-L-S1-12_stk   684262.597  6402725.101 348.883
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-1_stk    684155.521  6402733.296 345.127
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-2_stk    684155.514  6402728.608 345.188
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-3_stk    684155.53   6402723.407 345.226
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-4_stk    684155.524  6402718.2   345.306
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-5_stk    684155.526  6402713.094 345.34
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-6_stk    684155.527  6402708.002 345.397
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-7_stk    684155.531  6402702.891 345.4
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-8_stk    684155.52   6402697.597 345.494
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-9_stk    684155.524  6402692.499 345.555
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-10_stk   684155.532  6402687.406 345.609
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-11_stk   684155.533  6402682.217 345.645
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-12_stk   684155.524  6402677.043 345.698
36-005-EXT-R1-L-S1-13_stk   684155.534  6402672.309 345.757
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the behavior occurring under Excel 2019.

The large and very different values of the UTM coordinates (east, north) cause the problem of the missing trend line. The east values (here not having the optional UTM zone) are much smaller than the north values calculated from the equator. You know - your (fictitious?) posts of the solar farm have logically very small deviation from the aligment in east-west direction (30 mm) vs. the meridian direction (60 m). This is visually a bit problematic.

This said, you should trim the coordinates by an offset as much as possible.

Adding a trend line is resulting in:

[image]

A simple trend line to visualize the deviation from the aligment does not really help here from a technical point of view. You may want to plot the deviation from a mean e.g. using `=B2-AVERAGE($B$2:$B$12)` or the deviation from a selected post of the entire post series. Add a new column for this.

[image]